# Redux-saga: middleware not running my saga / first trigger not handled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

In my application I have 10+ straight forward sagas.
I use sagaMiddleWare to run my sagas:

`sagas.map(saga => { sagaMiddleware.run(saga)});`

With the following saga, where I want to do something different based on the payload of the action, I have difficulties making it work like I want to.

Right now it does work, apart from the first time the action is dispatched after loading the application. If I would retrigger the action, the effect gets triggered correctly. It looks like the saga is not running before the first request.

```
function* ordersRequestSaga() {
 const action = yield take(OrderActions.TypeKey.GET_ORDERS_REQUEST);
 switch (action.payload.requestType) {
 case OrderData.RequestType.Open:
  yield takeLatest(action.type, fetchOpenOrders);
  break;
 default:
  break; 
 }
}
```

If I would compose my code like this (without the take and switch, everything works from the get-go)

```
function* ordersRequestSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(OrderActions.TypeKey.GET_ORDERS_REQUEST, fetchOpenOrders);
 }
}
```

I know that a good solution would be to create a GET_OPEN_ORDERS_REQUEST etc..
But I really want to keep this structure. Wondering if anyone knows what could cause this behaviour, or even better, a solution... :D

Thanks

Comment: I think you should provide component code where you trigger saga

Comment: Well the component dispatches the action, this is the action that gets dispatched {type: "GET_ORDERS_REQUEST", payload: {…}}
payload: {
customerId:"010000300"
requestType:0` }

Comment: I afraid there is not enough information. It can be anything. You should provide some more code, ex. from your component and saga

Comment: @lomboboo It's basically the saga i'm posting, and I believe I must be violating something iside of it. I've edited my question. Thank you for helping

Comment: Component code will also help. Do you dispatch action on componentDidMount? Do you have google redux plugin for debug for happens on initial load?

Comment: Yes I did, in my debugger I see the Action being dispatch (redux dev-tools to), but saga effect is not being triggered

Comment: `function* ordersRequestSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(OrderActions.TypeKey.GET_ORDERS_REQUEST, fetchOpenOrders);
 }
}` is it watcher? why it has identical function name as generator above? And what is the `fetchOpenOrders ` function?
I suggest you to insert whole saga and component files or create simple jsfiddle that reproduces your issue